# Symfony doesn't display form properly

Tags: forms, symfony

I tried to display a simply form that I built in SearchType.php. In my controller, the form is supposed to be displayed with the route /search. But we we go there, I have just one input while I defined two input in SearchType.php. Note : this input is not even a selection, I only can enter text.

search.html.twig

```
{% extends 'base.html.twig' %}

{% block title %}Liste des sorties et des activités{% endblock %}

{% block main %}

    {{ form(form) }}

{% endblock %}
```

SearchType.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Form;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\ChoiceType;

class SearchType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options): void
    {
        $builder
            ->add('bigcity', ChoiceType::class, [
                'choices' => [
                    'Je sélectionne une ville' => '',
                    'Paris, France' => 'paris'
                ]
            ])
            ->add('category', ChoiceType::class, [
                'choices' => [
                    "Je sélectionne un type d'activité" => '',
                    'Eat Zpeak !' => 'eatzpeak',
                    'Party Zpeak !' => 'partyzpeak',
                    'Run Zpeak !' => 'runzpeak',
                    'Art Zpeak !' => 'artzpeak',
                ]
            ])
            ->add('save', SubmitType::class)
        ;
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver): void
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults([
            'data_class' => null
        ]);
    }
}
```

EventsController.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Controller;

use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Annotation\Route;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\SearchType;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\AbstractController;

class EventsController extends AbstractController
{   
    #[Route('/search', name: 'search')]
    public function search(Request $request)
    {   
        $form = $this->createForm(SearchType::class);
        $form->handleRequest($request);

        if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
            $data = $form->getData();
            return $this->render('front/events.html.twig', $data);
        }
        return $this->render('front/search.html.twig', [
            'form' => $form->createView()
        ]);
    }
}
```

Comment: I have a feeling, that you are always redirected to `front/events.html.twig`. You didn't configure your form to handle only POST requests. You could debug/verify this by `dd($data)` in if, where you check if form has been submitted & isValid. 
Also check if you already have another `/saerch` route, since symfony takes first match.
Just run `bin/console debug:route | grep search`

Comment: Hello V-Light. How do I debug/verify by dd($data) ? I don't have any button to validate and submit.

Comment: I added this just before (if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {) in order to handle only post requests : if ($request->isMethod('POST')) {$form->submit($request->request->get($form->getName())); It didn't change some thing.

Comment: I checked, I don't think I have an other "search" route.

Comment: As I am trying to make a search, don't you think I need to handle get requests instead of post ?

Comment: (Just tried. It's probably not right.)

Comment: For the search route, I created a link in the navbar that leads to search page. In the EventsController, I create the function that allows to land on search page with the route search.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are usinig a bad class import in your controller

> use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\SearchType;

You should use the namespace of your formType

> App\Form\SearchType